# Current through a solenoid: magnetic field gives a staircase graph

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, electromagnetic-induction, inductance, lenz-law

We were running current through a solenoid coil with an iron core, and measuring the resultant magnetic field strength. We expected a purely linear relation for the "current-field strength" graph.

However, our data resembles a stairway instead.
[image: Our measures plotted in a graph: data resembles a stairway with slanted stairs]

The plot refers to a solenoid with 400 windings (when using more windings we get more "steps") and can be accurately reproduced no matter what equipment we switch out.

We're completely stumped as to why we got this result. Our teacher has no clue and we haven't been able to find any resource on this effect.

Edit: Extra graphs
600 windings
[image]

800 windings
[image]

1600 windings
[image]

3200 windings
[image]

do note that the current axis is not the same for all of the graphs

If it's relevant to show how fast current was increased, here's current and time

Comment: Very interesting question! Can you edit to include the plot with extra windings? Is the iron core always the same in the two cases? May you repeat the experiment by changing the current in the solenoid SLOWER than you did and FASTER than you did? See "2. Induced Emf Due to a Change in Solenoid Field Due to a Change in Solenoid Current" here: https://www.webassign.net/question_assets/ketphysvl1/lab_14/manual.html -> I expect less oscillation  if the experiment is done very slowly :)

Comment: See also this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/600639/226902 "Why can't the current in a solenoid be changed rapidly?" https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228839/226902 "What happens if a current flows through a wire wrapped around a magnetised material?", https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406642/226902 "Magnetic flux inside solenoid"

Comment: Interesting graph!  It does not go through the origin (Current=0,H=0). Why is this? Is the iron core demagnetised at the beginning of the experiment?

Comment: Where and how did you measure the magnetic field strength? Details of the experiment might help provide an answer.

Comment: This looks similar but is probably different to well-known magnetization staircase due to domain wall jumps. https://sethna.lassp.cornell.edu/research/hysteresis . I think this may be due to measurement error (maybe actual current increased nonuniformly in time in a jump-like fashion)?

Comment: @JánLalinský I don't think it's related to domains because it's too regular (all domains equal?).

Comment: @Quillo I agree, this is something else.

Comment: @Quillo the current was increased very slowly, this data was made by increasing current, but when decreasing the same graph was discovered (albeit it might be a little bit scewed because of Hysteresis, but not by much). I've added extra graphs for other windings

Comment: Thank you @Valdemar, it's really interesting!

Answer (score 1):

You should get a linear or smooth exponential change in field strength. Possible explanations would require a careful look at any features of the test setup such as frictional hysteresis; power source variations such as an autotransformer whose voltage is derived from coil turns in the transformer. As a clue, does each ripple represent a change in the applied current?; is the voltage well filtered to eliminate a.c. ripple (alternations in voltage can affect the core iron magnetic hysteresis and thus the field).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/414225)